# Breeze sample fails with "resource cannot be found"

Tags: breeze

I downloaded a Breeze sample, opened it in Visual Studio, hit F5 to run it under debug (or ctrl-F5 without debugging) and IE reports "Requested URL: /Views/Home/Index.cshtml" could not be found.

The problem goes away if I set the project "Start action"  to "Specific page" via "Project | Properties | Web". I can leave the name of the page blank; just click that radio button.

Why don't you do that for us so that no one has to suffer this experience?

Comment: This was a question from a Breeze user and I've run into this myself many times. See answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sympathize having had this disconcerting experience myself many times. I wish we could do something about it. It's an artifact of an unfortunate interaction between MVC pages and Visual Studio.

Your suggestion - setting the "Specific Page" - does work and I recommend it to everyone. I only wish we could set it for you.

Unfortunately, this setting, like many others, is stored in the solution "**.suo**" file (e.g., "*Todo-Angular.v11.**suo***").

We don't keep the ".suo" files (nor the ".csproj.user" files) in source control and we don't ship them with the samples because these files are not "ours". They are technically "yours." The ".suo" files are "per user" files that capture your personal experience with the solution. They include what files you had open in the editor in your last session, what folders you've hidden, which regions are expanded or collapsed, and more. Maybe we should revisit our decision ... but it's industry practice to omit these files.

Therefore, because we have no way of setting the "Specific Page" flag for you, you'll have to set it yourself.

There is another factor, one you may not have noticed. You'll only experience this particular failure if the "*cshtml*" file (a) is currently selected in an open code editor or (b) is selected in Solution Explorer. Pick any non-*cshtml* (or non-*html*) file ... and the app starts just fine. Go figure.